# cannot access node values of xml in php

Tags: php, xml, laravel, post, curl

I am trying to access node values of xml using php. But I could not access any of them. However, the url is returning response. I am using cURL to send post request.

My code looks like

```
     $url = (some url);
  $postDatas = 'CompanyCode=' . urlencode($companyCode) . '&ServiceCode=' . urlencode($serviceCode) . '&Account=' .urlencode($account) . '&Special1=' .urlencode($special1) . '&Special2=' .urlencode($special2) . '&ExternalDate=' .urlencode($externalDate) . '&ExternalId=' .urlencode($externalId) . '&SalesPointType=' .urlencode($salesPointType) . '&UserName=' .urlencode($userName) . '&UserPassword=' .urlencode($userPassword);
                        $ch = curl_init( $url );
                        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postDatas);
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                        curl_close ($ch);
                        print_r($response);
```

When doing print_r($response), I am getting such xml response.

```
  <PPResponse Type="Check" Key="182f55a7-ed3f-e511-940e-005056b219f6" Result="000" OperationId="61289766243683">
      <ResultMessage>Operation was successfully completed.</ResultMessage>
      <ProviderInfo Code="962" Name="BSNL" Country="356" Currency="356">
        <PackagesList>
          <Package ServiceId="1" Name="Package 1.1" Value="110" Description="1.1 USD" />
          <Package ServiceId="1" Name="Package 2.2" Value="220" Description="2.2USD" />
          <Package ServiceId="1" Name="Package 4.4" Value="440" Description="4.4USD" />
        </PackagesList>
      </ProviderInfo>
    </PPResponse>
```

But when I do `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response)` and view it using `print_r($xml)`, I only get `Operation is completed successfully` and nothing else. But I want to access the value of all Result, OperationId and ResultMessage from this xml response. 
But when I save the same xml response in my local computer and try to fetch the data, I can fetch all node values but its not happening from url. I would like to know whats the problem with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run this code and get a nice XML ObjectSimpleXMLElement Object:

```
$string = '<PPResponse Type="Check" Key="182f55a7-ed3f-e511-940e-005056b219f6" Result="000" OperationId="61289766243683">
      <ResultMessage>Operation was successfully completed.</ResultMessage>
      <ProviderInfo Code="962" Name="BSNL" Country="356" Currency="356">
        <PackagesList>
          <Package ServiceId="1" Name="Package 1.1" Value="110" Description="1.1 USD" />
          <Package ServiceId="1" Name="Package 2.2" Value="220" Description="2.2USD" />
          <Package ServiceId="1" Name="Package 4.4" Value="440" Description="4.4USD" />
        </PackagesList>
      </ProviderInfo>
    </PPResponse>';
$text = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo "<pre>".print_r($text, true)."</pre>";
```

Result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Type] => Check
            [Key] => 182f55a7-ed3f-e511-940e-005056b219f6
            [Result] => 000
            [OperationId] => 61289766243683
        )

    [ResultMessage] => Operation was successfully completed.
    [ProviderInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [Code] => 962
                    [Name] => BSNL
                    [Country] => 356
                    [Currency] => 356
                )

            [PackagesList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Package] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ServiceId] => 1
                                            [Name] => Package 1.1
                                            [Value] => 110
                                            [Description] => 1.1 USD
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ServiceId] => 1
                                            [Name] => Package 2.2
                                            [Value] => 220
                                            [Description] => 2.2USD
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ServiceId] => 1
                                            [Name] => Package 4.4
                                            [Value] => 440
                                            [Description] => 4.4USD
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Make sure you print the decoded xml variable, not the response.